# Create different random x,y value to different class from a range that user inputs

Tags: c++, c, random

I create a class first

```
class Item
{
private:
   int x;
   int y;
}
```

and I get user input m(for example, 5),and user input n(for example, 4)
the question is how to create  different (x,y) value from 1 to 5 and assign them to the 4 class Item. 
I want to get result like 
(1,2) (2,2) (3,4) (4,1)  - As long as either x or y is different from other's.

I dont want to get result like
(1,2) (1,2)

PS : I know how to write public methods to assign the value to the properties of class
I just want to know how to create those value

PS2: This looks like to find different points' coordinates in a square

Comment: What if the user inputs 2 and 5? There are only 4 values in the range.

Comment: n is never greater than m^2, thanks for mentioning that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches you can take: compute all of the (i,j) pairs where (1 ≤ i ≤ m) and (1 ≤ j ≤ m), and then take n random pairs, or you can compute random pairs and check if you have already created them.

I will show the first since it is a bit easier to implement.  First, let's give the `Item` class a proper constructor.

```
class Item {
public:
    Item();
    Item(int x, int y);

    int x, y;
};

Item::Item() : x(0), y(0) { }

Item::Item(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) { }
```

Now let's put all of the items possible in an `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<Item> items;

for (int x = 1; x <= m; ++x) {
    for (int y = 1; y <= m; ++y) {
        items.push_back(Item(x, y));
        /* If you have C++11, this will be faster: items.emplace_back(x, y); */
    }
}
```

Now let's select a random `n` of those and put them into a vector.

```
std::vector<Item> chosen_items;

// Seed random number generator with the current time.
std::srand(std::time(0));

while (n--) {
    // Get a random number and make sure that it is within the bounds of the items
    // vector. Note that the modulus technique does not guarantee that the
    // distribution of random numbers will be uniform.
    int offset = std::rand() % items.size();

    // Get an iterator to this item.
    std::vector<Item>::iterator item = items.begin() + offset;

    // Move the item to the chosen_items list.
    chosen_items.push_back(*item);
    // C++11: chosen_items.emplace_back(*item);

    // Remove the item from the other list so we don't pick it again.
    items.erase(item);
}
```

You will need the following headers for this code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
```

([See a demo](http://ideone.com/cpgyAY).)

Comment: OMG!! This looks GORGEOUS! I need to try my best to understand the code thoroughly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

What about this

```
for(int i = 0; i < m && n > 0; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < m && n > 0; j++){
        // create Item (i,j) here
        n --;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code does create n of (x,y), But some of the (x,y) value would totally be the same using just assign a random value to (x[n],y[n])

Comment: I think my problem is actually how to create Item(i,j). How to create n different (i,j)